# Reverse proxy and .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, reverse-proxy

Is it possible to put a reverse proxy in an .htaccess file? Something like this:

```
ProxyPass /path/ http://128.10.10.10/
ProxyPassReverse /path/ http://128.10.10.10/
```

If not, are there other options?

**EDIT** Because I've got a domain like `domain.com` and a path in it like `/path` so that `domain.com/path` redirects to `128.10.10.10`.

This works, but I'd like to set it up so when I'm at `128.10.10.10` after the redirect the URL bar at the top of the browser reads `domain.com/path` and so that any subfolders therein would be accessible via `domain.com/path/subfolders`.

Comment: Why don't you just test it?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass):

> Context:  server config, virtual host, directory

Which doesn't include ".htaccess", and so the answer is no.

Comment: Would you happen to know if I can achieve a URL mask with `RewriteRule`? I want to replace `http://128.10.10.10/` with the domain this `.htaccess` file is on with the path of `/path` above. These rewrite rules confuse me.